# How can I get each numeric column's mean in one data?

Tags: r, mean

I have data named cluster_1. It has nominal variable from first column to the third.

```
# select the columns based on the clustering results
cluster_1 <- mat[which(groups==1),]

m_cluster_1 <-   mean(cluster_1[c(-(1:3))])
```

By the last statement, I can get the mean of all columns'. However, what I want is to attach the mean of each variable(column) to the bottom of the column.

How can I make it? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`colMeans()` will give you the mean of each column in a data frame or matrix. And `rbind()` can be used to append the result.

```
rbind(cluster_1[, -(1:3)], colMeans(cluster_1[, -(1:3)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still have a problem. I copied and pasted your answer but it did not work as I wish.

Comment: I use RStudio, and your answer works on console but it does not make any dataset.

Comment: cluster_1<-rbind(cluster_1[, -(1:3)], colMeans(cluster_1[, -(1:3)]))

Comment: Oh, I copied and pasted your answer after "cluster_1<-", and it did work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A generalization of what you are doing can be found with the function `addmargins`. Try, for example:

```
cluster_1Means <- addmargins(cluster_1[, -(1:3)], margin = 1, FUN = mean)
cluster_1Means
```